# Find the difference between two nested dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, compare

I have two nested dictionaries that are of type:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>>>
```

I was wondering what would be the most efficient/best way of finding the differences between the two, I would just be comparing keys, currently I have nested for loops looping around and comparing them however I don't think this is the most efficient way.

Comment: Your main problem is not the nested loops, its the nested dictionaries. Why do you need that? Are you sure that there isn't another way of do that?

Answer (score 3):

Iteration through keys is inevitable, so your algorithm will perform linearly at best (O(N) where N is length of collection of keys)
Now, accessing a dictionary member by index is a constant - O(1) operation, so just make sure you use indexer or TryGetValue method
As a result your algorithm should be liner in the size of the collection
Please note that instead of having multiple nested generic dictionaries, it would be **much better** to refactor to a composite key, ie have a struct with several string fields that represent a composite key, and then just use one Dictionary without nesting

Comment: I am pushing data in the form of a json object which will get deserialised by my application.  However the keys will be unknown which is why I went with nested dictionaries,  however I welcome better suggestions, does the way you mention also cater for variable keys?

Comment: Use Json.NET and classes that represent your data.

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez does Json .NET map keys to variable names? if so this probably won't work with the dataset that is being pushed to by application

Comment: It map keys to properties, yes. Check it, it have tons of ways to do the things you want.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to check what keys are in one dictionary but not in the other (or other operation you would usually perform on sets), you can use LINQ

```
var keysJustInFirst = dict1.Keys.Except(dict2.Keys);
var keysJustInSecond = dict2.Keys.Except(dict1.Keys);
var commonKeys = dict1.Keys.Intersect(dict2.Keys);
```

Comment: Please note that LINQ Except method will yield worse performance in terms of running time, namely O(N+M) where N and M are lengths of `dict1` and `dict2` keys collections. This is due to the fact of how `ExceptIterator` is implemented - internally it uses a `Set<TKey>` and loops through both key collections. Additionally it uses a O(N+M) storage, which is not required for this question - in my solution O(1) storage is used

Comment: Yes, the effort is O(N+M) - but considering you have to check each key in every dictionary at least once, this is the best you can hope to do

Comment: Agreed, if you need to find the full difference, then yes.
If it is enough to know whether elements are the same or not, you can do faster in best case because of short - circuiting - exiting iteration at first mismatch, which in the best case can be O(1)

Comment: @dyrssen I want to be able to get the difference both in key and value of the whole dictionary including the nested dictionaries

Comment: @Johnathon64 what is the end result? A bool saying if they are different? A dictionary containing the differences?

Comment: @dyrssen a dictionary containing the differences

Comment: @Johnathon64 ok, but how do you imagine this dictionary will look like? So considering you only had the most inner dictionary, what would be the result of comparing dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"key1", "value1"}, {"key2", "value2"}, {"key3", "value3"} } with dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string> { {"key1", "value1"}, {"key2", "notvalue2"}, {"key4", "value4"} }?